# Omitting the return of function with try/catch

Tags: r, machine-learning, rstudio, data-science

I created a script to automatize the load of packages with `try/catch`, so I would like do suppress the returns of script except the `messages` into `try blocks`.

However, when the code bellow is executed the return of the lists with the package names are returned in `Console`.

```
## Install Packages
# install.packages(httr)
# install.packages(jsonlite)
# install.packages(lubridate)
# install.packages(dplyr)
# install.packages(openxlsx)
# install.packages(tibble)
# install.packages(tidyr)
# install.packages(stringr)

# Store package names into a vector
pacotes <- c('httr', 'jsonlite', 'lubridate', 'dplyr', 'openxlsx', 'tibble', 'tidyr', 'stringr')

fun.loadPacotes <- function(pacotes) {
  out <- tryCatch(
    {

      invisible(lapply(pacotes, library, character.only = TRUE))

    },
    error=function(cond) {

      message(paste("FAIL TO LOAD:", pacotes))

      message("Error Message:")

      message(cond)

    },
    warning=function(cond) {

      message(paste("The package return a warning:", pacotes))

      message("Warning Message:")

      message(cond)

    },
    finally={

      message(paste("Package Loaded:", pacotes))

    }
  )    
  return(out)
}

# Run function and load the packages
lapply(pacotes, fun.loadPacotes)
```

When I run the command `invisible(lapply(pacotes, library, character.only = TRUE))`, the return is ok, without results in `Console`.

I would like to run this code so that it does not return the list of package names.

Comment: (1) I wonder if you need `withCallingHandlers` (perhaps with `invokeRestart("muffleWarning")`) instead of `tryCatch`, since the latter will terminate execution of your `expr` as soon as one warning is introduced. Do you intend to continue operation after a warning? (2) The return value from `fun.loadPacotes` will be `invisible`, but not from `lapply` (which ignores something invisible and happily returns its value visibly). If you manually did `fun.loadPacotes(pacotes[1])` it would be invisible as you intended. (Similarly, `lapply(1:2, invisible)` will never be invisible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns `out`.  If it returned `invisible(out)`, the result would be invisible.

You called `invisible()` near the top of your function, but invisibility is very transient.  Otherwise any function that did something like

```
x <- someFunctionReturningInvisibleResult()
x
```

would not have its result auto-printed.  So you can skip the call near the top.

If you want invisibility to be conditional, then you need to make it explicitly conditional, e.g. as the end of your function,

```
if (shouldBeInvisible)
  invisible(out)
else
  out
```

You don't generally need an explicit call to `return()`; you only need to use that if the value needs to be returned early.  But if you want to use it for stylistic reasons, the lines above could be written with redundant calls like

```
if (shouldBeInvisible)
  return(invisible(out))
else
  return(out)
```